# PHP OOP redeclare private method/function in child class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, private, redeclare

Inside php manual example http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#example-242 it is saying

> We can redeclare the public and protected method, but not private

what do they mean my that **i might not be getting how to use inheritance properly** but say we have this code.

```
class MyClass1 {
    public $public = 'Public 1';
    protected $protected = 'Protected 1';
    private $private = 'Private 1';

    function printHello1() {
        echo $this->public . " MyClass1 ". PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->protected . " MyClass1 " . PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->private . " MyClass1 " . PHP_EOL;
    }
}



class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {
    public $public = 'Public 2';
    protected $protected = 'Protected 2';
    private $private = 'Private 2';

    function printHello2() {
        echo $this->public . " MyClass2 ". PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->protected . " MyClass2 " . PHP_EOL;
        echo $this->private . " MyClass2 " . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$obj2 = new MyClass2();
$obj2->printHello1();
$obj2->printHello2();
```

will return

```
Public 2 MyClass1
Protected 2 MyClass1
Private 1 MyClass1

Public 2 MyClass2 
Protected 2 MyClass2 
Private 2 MyClass2
```

Seems like i am able to create another `$private` variable in `MyClass2` without any problem, so why they say its **we can't**?

yes it does not change `$private` variable in `MyClass1` when i use function `printHello1()` in parent class however when i run `printHello2()` in child class `MyClass2` it does show new value for `$private` variable.

Now question i have is this bad practice to:

1. Overwrite/Redeclare private property function in child class?
2. Create second function `printHello2()` in child class when there is one already in parent class, this makes code bit spaghettish isn't it?
3. Same exact logic apply s to private methods correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private` is limited to THAT particular class and its code. It is invisble to descendant classes. E.g. if you eliminate the `private $private` in MyClass2:

```
class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {
    // private $private = 'Private 2';
    ^^---literally the only change
```

and then run the code:

```
Public 2 MyClass1
Protected 2 MyClass1
Private 1 MyClass1
Public 2 MyClass2
Protected 2 MyClass2
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MyClass2::$private in /home/sites/ca.usask.vido-inout/html/z.php on line 25
 MyClass2
```

That's why you get `Private 1` and `Private 2`. private variables aren't "shared" within the family. You're not "overwriting" anything, because `private 1` doesn't exist in the descendant classes.